# DISTINCT on XML with CAST

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, distinct

I have 4 tables. The table does not contain any `foreign key` reference, where name is of type `xml`

t1:

```
| id  | name           |
+-----+----------------+
| a1  | <ID>a1<ID>     |
| a2  | <ID>a2<ID>     |
| a3  | <ID>a3<ID>     |
```

t2:

```
| id  | name        |   t1_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| b1  | <ID>b1<ID>  | a1           |
| b2  | <ID>b2<ID>  | a2           |
| b3  | <ID>b3<ID>  | a3           |
| b4  | <ID>b4<ID>  | a1           |
```

t3:

```
| id  | name        |   t2_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| c1  | <ID>c1<ID>  | b1           |
| c2  | <ID>c2<ID>  | b2           |
| c3  | <ID>c3<ID>  | b3           |
```

t4:

```
| id  | name        |   t3_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| d1  | <ID>d1<ID>  | c2           |
| d2  | <ID>d2<ID>  | c3           |
```

I need to get all associated data. 
When I specify 'a1' I expect something as,

```
| name         | name        |   name       |   name       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| <ID>a1<ID>   | <ID>b1<ID>  | <ID>c1<ID>   |              |
|              | <ID>b4<ID>  |              |              |
```

Obtained result:

```
| name         | name        |   name       |   name       |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| <ID>a1<ID>   | <ID>b1<ID>  | <ID>c1<ID>   |              |
| <ID>a1<ID>   | <ID>b4<ID>  |              |              |
```

To resolve this, I used

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST (a.name AS TEXT), CAST (b.name AS TEXT), CAST (c.name AS TEXT), CAST (d.name AS TEXT)
FROM t1 AS a

LEFT JOIN t2 AS b
ON b.id = 
CAST((xpath('/ID/text()', b.name))[1] AS TEXT) 

LEFT JOIN t3 AS c
ON c.id = 
CAST((xpath('/ID/text()', c.name))[1] AS TEXT) 

LEFT JOIN t4 AS d
ON d.id = 
CAST((xpath('/ID/text()', d.name))[1] AS TEXT)
```

The above is not working. How to resolve this. Is this the optimized query? I tried nested queries. The `Distinct` problem occurs there also

***What is the best and optimized way to achieve this? Using `JOIN` or `Nested query`?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you display does not match the logic in the table samples. This would:

```
SELECT t1.name::text, t2.name::text, t3.name::text, t4.name::text
FROM   t1
LEFT   JOIN t2 b ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
LEFT   JOIN t3 c ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
LEFT   JOIN t4 d ON t4.t3_id = t3.id
WHERE  t1.id = 'a1';
```

And nothing in your question warrants the use of `DISTINCT`.

If you actually want to hide repeated names in the same column of the ordered list like displayed:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN name1 END AS name1
     , CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN name2 END AS name2
     , CASE WHEN rn3 = 1 THEN name3 END AS name3
     , name4
FROM  (
   SELECT t1.name::text AS name1, t2.name::text AS name2, t3.name::text AS name3, t4.name::text AS name4
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER ORDER BY t2.id, t3.id, t4.id) AS rn1
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id, t2.id ORDER ORDER BY t3.id, t4.id) AS rn2
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id, t2.id, t3.id ORDER ORDER BY t4.id) AS rn3
   FROM   t1
   LEFT   JOIN t2 b ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
   LEFT   JOIN t3 c ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
   LEFT   JOIN t4 d ON t4.t3_id = t3.id
   WHERE  t1.id = 'a1'
   ) sub
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id;
```

Comment: Clever. I don't see where rn4 is created though in your example.

Comment: @Joe: Right, `name4` can be displayed unconditionally. Thanks.